# Unexpected data-type while creating table

Tags: sql

[image]

I wanted to create attribute name,address with data type varchar, instead it created with type varchar2.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, then the interface you are using did you a favor.  `varchar2()` is the preferred variable length string type in Oracle.

Comment: How can i change the default?

Comment: If you are using Oracle, then you should [edit] the tags of this question, to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE student
MODIFY crn varchar(11);
```

Alternatively, since this is a new table (not likely to have data in it yet) you can just drop the thing and replace the whole thing using the correct data type

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: Did it work? If not, just drop the table and enter the CREATE TABLE query again.

Comment: I am using 11.2 and I see the same behavior.  What do you perceive to be the benefit of VARCHAR instead of VARCHAR2?

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't heard of VARCHAR2 before viewing this question. I was more concerned with answering the question rather than investigating the intricacies of data types. If @SuryaBhusal is asking how to alter a table on this site I'd wager that his skill level may not be enough to warrant using VARCHAR2. In some cases (and I believe this is one of them) going simpler is better.

Comment: Oracle's documentation 'suggests' that it is better to use VARCHAR2 rather than VARCHAR and hints that VARCHAR may, at some point, go away or have it's functionality changed.  Conjecture on my part, but it may be that we are no longer allowed to use the VARCHAR data type; as evidenced by the override behavior Surya and I have seen.

Comment: Briefly picking through some Oracle forums, it looks like you're right. I hesitate to say that we can't still use VARCHAR (especially as a teaching tool), but VARCHAR does seem to be on its way out. I'll keep that in mind for future Oracle questions